# GET from node to laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, http

I have 2 server, one Node and one Laravel. I should do a GET request from Node to Laravel using the request package but Laravel response is always "unauthorized". How can i login from Node to Laravel with a specific username and password to do the GET request i need to do after?

Comment: [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport) is likely your easiest option.

Comment: How authorization is implemented in the Laravel application? Most likely you need to pass access token in every request from node.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already configured API routers and functions. Just need to add authentication mechanism?
The easiest way is to add JWT or Laravel Passport. I prefer the Passport since It uses OAuth. However you can also add JWT as well. It's pretty simple. [Please check this documentation.](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/)